# The destructor of the current Page in Frame was not called after I pressed "X" to close the application

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt, winui, windows-app-sdk

Compiling the following code snippet in Release mode. Running the application, and clicking "X" to close the application, it is found that the destructor of FirstPage has not been called.

1. App.xaml.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "App.xaml.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using namespace AppTest;
using namespace AppTest::implementation;

App::App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
void App::OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const&)
{
    window = make<MainWindow>();
    window.Activate();
}
```

2. MainWndow.xaml:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="AppTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <RelativePanel>
        <Frame Name="frameContent"/>
    </RelativePanel>
    
</Window>
```

3. MainWindow.xaml.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#endif

#include "FirstPage.xaml.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::AppTest::implementation
{
    MainWindow::MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this->frameContent().Navigate(winrt::xaml_typename<AppTest::FirstPage>());
    }
}
```

4. FirstPage.xaml.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "FirstPage.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("FirstPage.g.cpp")
#include "FirstPage.g.cpp"
#endif

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::AppTest::implementation
{
    FirstPage::FirstPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    FirstPage::~FirstPage()
    {
        /* Do something to know that the destructor has been called */
    }
}
```

I tried:

1. Running the Application.
2. Press the 'X' to close the Application.

Expected behavior:
The destructor of FirstPage should be called.

Actually resulted:
The destructor of FirstPage was not called.

---

Here is the minimal, reproducible [visual studio project sample](https://github.com/YjFnajEz/winui3_cppwinrt_AppTest).

Comment: A release configuration is optimized. If the compiler can prove that calling a function (such as a destructor) and not calling a function has the same effect, it can elide the function call. Start by observing the behavior of an unoptimized debug configuration.

Comment: @IInspectable In Debug mode, the destructor of FirstPage is not called either. If I navigate to BlankPage using this->frameContent().Navigate(winrt::xaml_typenameAppTest::BlankPage()); in MainWindow, the destructor of FirstPage will be called. However, if I now click the X button to close the program, the destructor of BlankPage will not be called.

Comment: I cannot reproduce using [C++ WinUI Custom Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-cppwinrt-winui-3). A new page raises a *Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999* for me. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample?

Comment: [winui3_cppwinrt_AppTest](https://github.com/YjFnajEz/winui3_cppwinrt_AppTest) is the minimal, reproducible sample. @YangXiaoPo-MSFT

Comment: Reproduced. I'm consulting this next Monday and you can also consult this at WindowsAppSDK [Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues).

Comment: I have consulted this at WindowsAppSDK, but it has been moved to microsoft-ui-xaml. @YangXiaoPo-MSFT

Comment: @JoJo I have also escalated this and am waiting for a response.

Comment: I bet the app simply exits and doesn't tear down the frame. This follows the principle of "When the process is exiting, don't bother cleaning up."